# TransportError(503, u'') when trying to use a recently created elasticsearch index

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm creating an Elasticsearch index using Python API like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

index_body = {"mappings": {".percolator": {"properties": {"message": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "english"}}}}}
# Creates the index if it doesn't exist
if not es.indices.exists('test'):
    es.indices.create(index='test', body=index_body)

print es.exists(index='test', id='1')
```

The index is created successfully, but when I check for the existence of a document inside the index it fails with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    print es.exists(index='test', id='1')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 68, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py", line 282, in exists
    self.transport.perform_request('HEAD', _make_path(index, doc_type, id), params=params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 86, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 102, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError: TransportError(503, u'')
```

If I run this script a second time, with the index already created it works just fine.
Does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong?

Comment: Please look in your `/var/log/elasticsearch/<nodename>.log` , it could contain more information. `503` is usually indicating a problem with the cluster in some way. Maybe the index is not yet created (in the cluster) when you already send the next request? Does it work if you wait a second before trying `es.exists`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I add a `time.sleep(1)` before `es.exists(index='test', id='1')` it works perfectly. No information in the log file though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a new index, you need to wait until all shards are allocated.

The best way I know of how to do is this:

1. fetch `<your_index>/_status`
2. iterate over all `indices.<your_index>.shards` and verify that `routing.state = STARTED` everywhere
3. Go to 1) unless all shards are started

[Here's a (PHP) project](https://github.com/ruflin/Elastica/blob/master/test/lib/Elastica/Test/Base.php#L81-L92) which did this for unit tests:

```
protected function _waitForAllocation(Index $index)
{
    do {
        $settings = $index->getStatus()->get();
        $allocated = true;
        foreach ($settings['shards'] as $shard) {
            if ($shard[0]['routing']['state'] != 'STARTED') {
                $allocated = false;
            }
        }
    } while (!$allocated);
}
```

**Wrong answer:**

You've to give ES *some space* before your continue. ES is *near realtime*, so delays are to be expected. Especially when you're running your code sequentially with next to no delay.

I think you simply need to call the [`_refresh` endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) and you're covered.

In practice I've to do the same in my unit tests. They execute very fast and creating/pumping data/destroying indices takes time so in my `setUp()` I've a call to `_refresh` before handing over to the respective `test*()` method. And in some tests, where I index data, I also have to place `_refresh` calls.

Usually, during *normal operation* you don't need to call it shouldn't. Keep in mind that the default `refresh_interval` is `1s`. If you're regularly update your index and expect sub-second updates to be reflected (I'm talking about e.g. `_search`), that's where you need to start.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Calling the refresh endpoint once didn't help, but if I call it twice it did. I think it has to do with the _space_ you were talking about. Seem like ES needs a second or two to actually create the index.

Comment: Ah I see. I was on the wrong track although I knew about the problem. You need to wait for the allocations of all shards -> I've updated the answer. Sorry :)

Comment: Yep, there's quite a bit of waiting around for ES to prepare things... no doubt in the nature of the beast.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the parameter wait_for_active_shards (defaults to 1) like so:

es.indices.create(index='test', body=index_body, wait_for_active_shards=all)

See also: the elasticsearch-py manual for [create(**kwargs)](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.create)